# limiting point of $\|f(x)\|_p$ as $p\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, limits

I tried to calculate the limiting values of the p norm $\|f(x)\|_p$ for the following simple function:

$$f(x)=x, 0\leq a\leq x\leq b$$

\begin{eqnarray}
\|f(x)\|_p&=&\bigg[\int_{a}^b|x|^pdx\bigg]^\frac{1}{p}\\
&=&\bigg[\frac{b^{p+1}-a^{p+1}}{p+1}\bigg]^\frac{1}{p}
\end{eqnarray}

I stuck with the limiting point as $p\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: your definition of the $L^p$ norm is missing the absolute value symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the hypothesis, $b/a\gt1$

$$\bigg[\frac{b^{p+1}-a^{p+1}}{p+1}\bigg]^\frac{1}{p}=$$

$$=\bigg[b^{p+1}\frac{1-a^{p+1}/b^{p+1}}{p+1}\bigg]^\frac{1}{p}=$$

$$=\bigg[b^{p+1}\frac{1-\frac{1}{(b/a)^{p+1}}}{p+1}\bigg]^\frac{1}{p}=$$

$$=\left(b^{p+1}\right)^{1/p}\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{(b/a)^{p+1}}\right)^\frac{1}{p}}{(p+1)^\frac{1}{p}}=$$

$$=bb^{1/p}\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{(b/a)^{p+1}}\right)^\frac{1}{p}}{(p+1)^\frac{1}{p}}\to_{p\to\infty}b·1\frac 11=b$$

As expected.